# Inserting into a list within a list python

Tags: python, list, insert

I am trying to insert something into a list within a list and I couldn't figure out how to go doing that.

For example, I have a list of lists:

```
List1 = [[10, 13, 17], [3, 5, 1]]
```

and I want to insert `5` into sublist with index 0 after element `13` so it would look like this:

```
List1 = [[10, 13, 5, 17], [3, 5, 1]]
#                 ^
```

Comment: use list.insert(index, value) function

Comment: `List1[0].insert(2, 5)`

Answer (score 2):

This will do it. Using `.insert()` allows you to specify index as well the element and you can do it `inplace`. No need to assign the output.

```
List1 = [[10,13,5,17],[3,5,1]]
List1[0].insert(2,5)
print(List1)
```

**Output**

`[[10, 13, 5, 17], [3, 5, 1]]`